# PDO dynamic queries with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, dynamic-queries

I have a PDO class wrapper:

```
class DB {

        private $dbh;
        private $stmt;

        private $queryCounter = 0;

        public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbname) {

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname;

            $options = array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
            );

            try {
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                die();
            }
        }

        public function query($query) {
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            return $this;
        }

        public function bind($pos, $value, $type = null) {

            if( is_null($type) ) {
                switch( true ) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }

             $this->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
             return $this;
        }

        public function execute($vars = array()) {
                $this->queryCounter++;

                if (isset($vars) && count($vars)) {
                    foreach ($vars as $k => $v ) {
                        $this->bind(($k+1), $v);
                    }
                }

                return $this->stmt->execute();
        }

        public function resultset($vars = array()) {
            $this->execute($vars);
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function single($vars = array()) {
            $this->execute($vars);
            return $this->stmt->fetch();
        }
    }
```

My dynamic query is here:

```
        $per_page           = ($filter["show_by"] >= 25 && $filter["show_by"] <= 100) ? intval($filter["show_by"]) : 25; 
        $start          = intval($filter["page_id"]) ?  ($filter["page_id"] -1)*$per_page : 0;

        $sql_counter    = 'SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `products` WHERE 1=1';
        $sql_result = 'SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE 1=1';

        $data = [];

        if (isset($filter["mode"]) != 'extra') {

            $sql_counter    .= ' AND `status` = :status';
            $sql_result     .= ' AND `status` = :status';

            $data[":status"] = 1;

        }

        if (intval($filter["category_id"])) {

            $sql_counter    .= ' AND FIND_IN_SET(:category_id, `cid`)';
            $sql_result     .= ' AND FIND_IN_SET(:category_id, `cid`)';

            $data[":category_id"] = $filter["category_id"];
        }       

        if (strlen($filter["search_by"]) > 0) {

            $search          = '%'.filter_var($filter["search_by"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING).'%';
            $sql_counter    .= ' AND `name` LIKE :search';
            $sql_result     .= ' AND `name` LIKE :search';

            $data[":search"] = $search;
        }   

        /*print_r($sql_counter);
        print_r($data);
        die();
        */

        $count  = $this->db->query($sql_counter)->single($data)[0];
```

But this returns me an error:

```
 PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

My debug info is below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `products` WHERE 1=1 AND `status` = :status AND FIND_IN_SET(:category_id, `cid`) AND `name` LIKE :search

Array
(
    [:status] => 1
    [:category_id] => 7
    [:search] => %123%
)
```

Question: Where is a bug?
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions like "Please watch my code and tell me where is a bug" are sure offtopic here. SO is not a free debugging service, mind you. Not to mention that humans usually have no PHP interpreter in their heads to run your code by means of watching it.

Comment: Why oh why do people dump complex code that doesn't work?? Did a simple version work?? Did it work after adding more code?? When did it stop stop working ?? This is basic programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, questions like "Please watch my code and tell me where is a bug" are sure offtopic on this site.

the only *answer* possible is to tell you how to debug your query and how to localize the problem.

Look, you have a query and parameters.

Try to run it with raw PDO. Does it work?
If not - try to take out your conditions (along with corresponding parameters) one by one. On which one it stopped? Can you reproduce the problem with this one?

Try to narrow your problem down as much as possible. that's the only way anyway.

Comment: The purpose of all that mess is not to " find the bug" but **to narrow down the problem,** taking out all the unnecessary stuff. Did you?